# how to display group data in mvc view My view in not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have One partial_view in there i heaved  passed one data table of schema details.
I want too there display view like below
Schema_Details Table:

```
SType : Equity
S_Name|Allocation|Lum_Sum_Value|SIP
 Xyz   |30%      |250000       |2000
```

In controller i get the data Group By 
My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public Action Result recommended-portfolio(int sName)
 {
   using (var db = new WFTradeEntities())
    {

var tr = db.Schema_Details.ToList().Where(x => x.RID == sName).Select(x => new Schema_Details
   {
     SID = x.SID, RID = x.RID,Schema_Name = x.Schema_Name,SType = x.SType,
     InvestmentType = x.InvestmentType, Allocation = x.Allocation,
     Lum_Sum_Amount = x.Lum_Sum_Amount,
        cal = Convert.ToDouble(x.Allocatio/100.0 * 25000), 
      SIP=Convert.ToDouble(x.Allocation / 100.0 * 5000)}).GroupBy(x => x.SType);
   return PartialView("_PortfolioTable", tr);
        }
    }
```

My View In not Display the Gird:

My View data:
 @model IEnumerable

```
   @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.SType)) 
    { 
         @Html.Encode(group.Key) 
         @foreach (var item in group) { 
         @Html.Encode(item.Schema_Name)
     }
```

Comment: is there a reason you are returning a PartialView?  this doesn't look right. what is it displaying or what error are you getting?

Comment: @Emil there is reason.n no error coming only not displaying the grid

Comment: i think your view is not loading the PartialView, you cannot return a PartialView from a main action call. PartialViews are called from inside a view

Comment: now it is worked @Emil

Comment: what was the problem? did my answer help?

Comment: @Emil i m sorry but answer not getting help for me but i think about n remove in controllepby then its worked